# Getting the json values where one of the attributes match ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a JSON file

```
  { "data": [
      {
          "channel_id":"test1",
          "who_to_ping":"user124",
          "workflow_status":"enabled",
          "non_workflow_status":"disabled",
          "auto_response_status":"enabled"
     },
     {
          "channel_id":"test2",
          "who_to_ping":"user476",
          "workflow_status":"enabled",
          "non_workflow_status":"disabled",
          "auto_response_status":"enabled"
     }
]}
```

I can access the data and set the new user by doing this:

```
channel_id = "test1"
name = "new user"
file_path = "#{Rails.root}/public/slack_config.json"
file = File.read(file_path)
data_hash = JSON.parse(file)
data_hash['data'][0]['who_to_ping'] = name
File.write(file_path, JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.dump(data_hash)))
```

What I need to do is update only the array where channel_id matches. For example channel_id will be a variable passed in, it might be test1, test2 or another value. If I want to update who_to_ping for test1 to a new name `data_hash['data'][0]['who_to_ping']` is not going to work when the value passed is dynamic.

I could do a search to see which element the channel_id matches, then if its the 8th element do data_hash['data'][7]['who_to_ping'] but I am sure there is a more efficient way. It is probably a simple one but my search is not bringing up anything but my not sure what the correct search terms are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can iterate and map through `data_hash['data']` check if the channel_id inside the data matches the passed one and then change if so

```rb
data_hash['data'] = data_hash['data'].map do |data| # you can remove data_hash['data'] = and replace it by a destructible map! 
  if data['channel_id'] == channel_id
    data['who_to_ping'] = name
    # change other fields here too if you want
  end
  data # make sure to return data so the mapping work
end

File.write(file_path, JSON.pretty_generate(data_hash)) # no need to use dump as pretty_generate already will transform your hash into json
```

Comment: This worked great but the only issue is it messes up the formatting on the json file when I write it back to the file, ends up looking like this: "{\"data\":[{\"channel_id\":\"my_id\",\"who_to_ping\":\"<@test1>\"

Comment: to store the JSON you only need to call `pretty_generate` in your case pretty generate will call generate internally which will transform your hash into JSON (the equivalent to dump in your case): `File.write(file_path, JSON.pretty_generate(data_hash))`

Comment: Ah your a genius, I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why it was happening but that makes sense and fixed the problem. Thanks for making my day Mshka